# How to print specific Column values of the filtered Row

Tags: java, jtable, rowfilter

**ID** | **Name** | **Category**
101 | Dumplings | Chicken
102 | Burger | Chicken
103 | Pizza | Cheese

When I select chicken in combobox, the row of JTable with Chicken that is the first and second row gets displayed by using RowFilter.

In this case,

```
TableRowSorter sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(model)
Table.setRowSorter(sorter)
RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Object> filter= RowFilter.regexFilter(combo1.getSelectedItem().toString(),2);
Sorter.setRowFilter(sorter)
```

My question is how do I print the row of column 1 when it is filtered.

If I click chicken in the category then the table gets filtered and i want to print  all the column 1 values. Since the row gets filtered we have two chicken item:
Dumplings
Burger

And If I click cheese in the category then the table gets filtered and i want to print  the column 1 values. Since the row gets filtered we have one cheese item:
Pizza

And I want to print the column value when it the corresponding table is filtered by category
How do i do that?